# Get active menu element and display its title AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, directive

How to retrieve the element class and display its name?

I read that I can use sth like:

```
var elementResult = element[0].getElementsByClassName('menu-item-active');
      console.log('element[0].getElementsByClassName: ', elementResult);
```

JSON :

```
{
    "title": "Fruits",
    "mainmenu": [
        {
            "id": "apples",
            "title": "Apples",
            "href": "#/apples",
            "act": "menu-item-active"
        },
        {
            "id": "bananas",
            "title": "Bananas",
            "submenu": [
                 {
                     "id": "banana-box",
                     "title": "Banana Box",
                     "href": "#/banana-box",
                     "act": "menu-item-active"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a directive

```
.directive('dir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:  "<nav class=\"navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top\" role=\"navigation\" id=\"nav-bar\">"
                        + "<div class=\"container-fluid\">"
                            + "<div class=\"navbar-header\">"
                                + "<span class=\"navbar-brand\" >{{title}} </span>" 
                            + "</div>"
                            + "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\" ng-repeat=\"item in mainmenu\">"
                                + "<li>"
                                    + "<a href=\"{{item.href}}\" data-active-menu-link=\"{{item.act}}\">{{item.title}}</a>"
                                + "</li>"
                            + "</ul>"
                        + "</div>"
                    + "</nav>"
           }
});
```

And the controller:

```
   .module('menu').controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('MenuItems.json').success(function (data) {
            $scope.mainmenu = data.mainmenu;
            $scope.title = data.title;
        });
    }]);
```

**What I want to achieve:**
when I will be on the each site/subsite and I want to display its name as {{title}} in my site

I tried to use the `elementResult` but I don't know how to check if the element is `menu-item-active`. I thought about using the `ng-if` statement, but I don't know how to handle it.

For.ex. 
`ng-if="elementResult has class 'menu-item-active' then display its 'title' as {{title}} in menu bar`

Comment: Your JSON is invalid for a start.. You can't have property names in an array etc. Could you fix that an update your question with the correct JSON please.

Comment: I don't get what's wrong in the JSON file? 
edit: I saw one mistake, I corrected it

Comment: Makes no sense trying to change title from an element class. Why can't you use route parameters for this? Or tie the directive to a service. Searching the DOM is just a backwards approach since the class should probably be set by data in the model in the first place

Comment: I didn't tried route parameters, but I saw some examples

Answer (score 0):

In dom, getElementByClassName returns NodeList.

```
var nodeList = element[0].getElementsByClassName('menu-item-active');
```

So then you have to iterate over nodes. You can use it's length property.

```
for ( var i = 0 ; i < nodeList.length ; i++ ) 
    if ( nodeList[i].className == 'menu-item-active' ) 
        var elem = $scope.findByClassName('menu-item-active');
```

and in your controller write scope method:

```
$scope.findByClassName = function(id){
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length ; i++ ) 
        if ( jsonArray[i].mainmenu.act == id ) 
            return jsonArray[i].title;
    }
```

Also prepare proper JSON file - key value pairs and arrays of objects ( these starting with { and ending with } ).

Also, in Angular you can pass to param to a page/view, so you can use routes and $routeParam service must be dependency injected in your controller. Then for page "new/3" you ask for `"$routeParams.id"` and you will get 3.

Comment: I think this is an extremely backwards way of doing something that should be doable completely on the model level. No need to look at any DOM elements - let data binding handle that.